# Order google docs Bookmarks by their absolute position in the document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I didn't find a way to get the list of Bookmarks sorted by their absolute position in the document.

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var bookmarksList = doc.getBookmarks();
```

bookmarksList is not ordered by the position.

In order to do that I suppose I can write something:

```
var bookmarksList = doc.getBookmarks().sort(sortBookmarkByPosition);
```

so using a custom sort function

```
function sortBookmarkByPosition(a,b){
  return what_to_return_here;
}
```

The problem is that Position.getOffset() "Gets this Position's relative location within the element that contains it."

Is there a solution to get the Bookmarks order by their absolute position in the document?

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution.
It's not so good for performance, but it seems to work.

Sorting the bookmarks for the absolute position of the bookmarks in the documents should be the same as sorting for the **number of Elements** contained in the document between the start of the document and the Element at the Position of each Bookmark.

Following there's my solution:

```
function sortBookmarkByPosition(a,b){

  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  bodyElem = body.getChild(0);

  aElem = a.getPosition().getElement();
  bElem = b.getPosition().getElement();

  // a 
  var rangeBuilder = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().newRange();  
  rangeBuilder.addElementsBetween(bodyElem, aElem); 
  var aCount = rangeBuilder.getRangeElements().length; 

  // b
  rangeBuilder = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().newRange();
  rangeBuilder.addElementsBetween(bodyElem, bElem);
  var bCount = rangeBuilder.getRangeElements().length;

  return aCount - bCount;
}
```

Please comment it if you see some errors. Better solutions are really welcome :-).